# multiple diifferent aasm implementations on different columns of a model

Tags: ruby-on-rails-3

i have a model as below

```
class Inspection < ActiveRecord::Base
  include AASM

  aasm_column :status  #aasm in 'status' field
  aasm_initial_state :new
  aasm_state :new
  aasm_state :inprocess
  aasm_state :complete
  aasm_state :approved

  aasm_event :inprocess do
    transitions :to => :inprocess, :from => :new
  end

  aasm_event :complete do
    transitions :to => :complete, :from => :inprocess
  end

  aasm_event :approve do
    transitions :to => :approved, :from => :complete
  end


  aasm_column :sharing_status  #aasm in 'sharing_status' field
  aasm_initial_state :not_shared
  aasm_state :not_shared
  aasm_state :shared
  aasm_state :revoked

  aasm_event :share do
    transitions :to => :shared, :from => :not_shared
  end

  aasm_event :revoke do
    transitions :to => :revoked, :from => :shared
  end

  .....
end
```

i want to implement different aasm states and transitions on two different model **fields** of **Inspection**. the first transition doesnt work in the above code(if the second state and transitions are present). How can this be solved?

Comment: @bobomoreno if u set this as an answer, i will accept it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I have the same issue
it seems it is not supported on AASM to have multiple state models on the same model, however plugin 'state_machine' does support this.

https://github.com/pluginaweek/state_machine